# How can i let my console window open? VB

Tags: vb.net, console, basic

I want to let my console window open in Visual Basic. With my code that i have, i only can ask for one line and then the window closes. Here is my code:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()

    If (Console.ReadLine = "e") Then
        Console.WriteLine("Test")
    End If

    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub

End Module
```

So when i run this code i can type "e" press enter. The word appears "Test" and then the console closes after pressing one key. But i want to let it open until i write a special word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a silly example:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim password As String = "007"

    Dim response As String
    Do
        Console.Write("Password: ")
        response = Console.ReadLine
        If response <> password Then
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Password!")
        End If
    Loop While response <> password

    Console.WriteLine("Welcome James Bond!")
    Console.Write("Press [Enter] to proceed...")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works how i want it to be!